# Remove Jetpack’s Open Graph meta tags for specific page

Tags: wordpress, jetpack

I want to remove Jetpack’s Open Graph meta tags for certain page by page/post ID.

I have tried to add this code to the theme function.php

add_filter( 'jetpack_enable_open_graph', '__return_false' );

It works but for the entire post/page. So, how to make it only applied for a certain post/page ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
add_filter( 'jetpack_enable_open_graph', 'custom000_jetpack_enable_open_graph', 100, 2 );
function custom000_jetpack_enable_open_graph( $return_false, $int ){

  if ( is_page() || is_single() ) {
    global $post;
    // Array of post IDs where you want it disabled
    $ids = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
    if( in_array($post->ID, $ids) ){
      return false;
    }
  }

  return $return_false;

}
```

Comment: Thanks Ali, I tried it but I got an error: Missing argument 2 for custom000_jetpack_enable_open_graph()

Comment: The code also affects for all post pages, the Jetpack’s Open Graph meta tags being disabled on all posts.